# How to re-hide div after showing it?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

So far I have [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/DnJ2z/11/). The div shows after scrolling past othdiv. Any ideas how to hide the div again after I scroll past the div in the opposite direction?

```js
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#dvid").hide(); //hide your div initially
  var topOfOthDiv = $("#othdiv").offset().top;
  $(window).scroll(function() {
    if ($(window).scrollTop() > topOfOthDiv) { //scrolled past the other div?
      $("#dvid").show(200); //reached the desired point -- show div
    }
  });
});
```

```css
body {
  height: 800px;
  font-family: 'Arial', Helvetica, Sans-Serif;
  color: white;
  font-weight: bold;
}
#othdiv {
  height: 50px;
  background-color: rgb(0, 140, 200);
  /*just wanted this to be pretty :)*/
  position: absolute;
  top: 200px;
  left: 0px;
}
#dvid {
  background-color: rgb(34, 177, 76);
  height: 50px;
  position: absolute;
  top: 260px;
  left: 100px;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div id="othdiv">
  If you scroll past me, then you'll see the other div.
</div>
<div id="dvid">
  Oh hello! :D
</div>
```

Comment: Would it not work to just hide the div inside of the same scroll function?

Comment: Just add another if inside of the scroll function that detects when you scroll to less than or equal to the top  of the div and consequently hide it.